# Can a switch be used to set HTML element attributes in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ng-switch

I've got some nice logic in an HTML element to switch an attribute value between 2 options using if:

```
<igx-icon [name]="cell.value=='Modified' ? 'mode_edit' : 'file_upload'"></igx-icon>
```

Do I have a similar option if I had more than 2 cases? I know I could:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="cell.value">
    <igx-icon *ngSwitchCase="Modified" name="mode_edit></igx-icon>
    <igx-icon *ngSwitchCase="Uploaded" name="file_upload"></igx-icon>
    <igx-icon *ngSwitchCase="Third Case" name="thirdOption"></igx-icon>
</div>
```

but it's not as brief of direct as the first form. Is there a tool to be used to accomplish this directly on the name property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a dictionary on your component to help with this:

```js
ExampleComponent {
    igxIconTypes = {
        'Modified': 'name',
        'Uploaded': 'file_upload',
        ...
    };
}
```

You could then use it like this in your template:

```html
<igx-icon [name]="igxIconTypes[cell.value]"></igx-icon>
```

You could then set up a default case (in which there wasn't a match) by using the `||` operator like this:

```html
<igx-icon [name]="igxIconTypes[cell.value] || 'default_icon'"></igx-icon>
```